# Magento Iphone Mobile theme Home page issue

Tags: magento

Hello

I am trying to setup an iphone theme for my magento store.

Following is my strore setup:

1. For my store i have selected a CMS page as my default home page

2. I have taken the default iphone theme and uploaded it to my themes folder

3. Under System > Configuration > Design > Themes > Templates, i have put the following under Matched Expression:

iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

The same is also Skin / Layout / Default

This should call the iphone theme into play when the website is viewed through any mobile device.

PLEASE NOTE: I want my CMS page set as home page to be visible for my website always. It is only when my website is viewed through a mobile device that i want the categories page to be displayed in conformance with iphone width and height display.

.

THE PROBLEM:

1. The home page of the iphone theme is showing the CMS page: I want to show categories straight away. How do i achieve this ??

2. The home page is also showing widths and heights that are consistent with the main website.... it is NOT showing it in dimensions favourable to an iphone/mobile device... THE PAGE IS SCROLLING LEFT AND RIGHT, because the width is default width.

This is probably so because that even when the website is viewed through a mobile device, the default CMS page set as home page is shown. This cms page has width that is in conformance of a normal laptops viewing screen. It has a wide banner image that is 960px in width. So, the solution here might be calling a category page which is in conformance of an iphone screen.... thus the need of 1 above.

Im sure this is NOT how an iphone site is supposed to be displayed.

Any suggestions as to where i might be going wrong.

Looking forward to all inputs and suggestions

Thanks to all

Moody

Comment: I can help you with No.1 - System->Configuration->General->Web->Default Pages and assign the home page to a CMS page in which you've added a code block which loads products.  ie {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Comment: Hi McNab... thanxs for ur solution... wanted to clarify something: for my website i want to keep the cms page i have created to be the default page. It is only with the Mobile themes that i want the home page to be the categories page. !!! in other words the CMS page will be bye passed only when viewed through a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
```

into the `<cms_index_index><reference name="content">` tag

see this example:

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="homepage.banner" translate="label">
            <label>Home Page Banner(Mobile)</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>front-banner</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="hp_nav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml" />
        <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```